# Check for Valid Values between two DecimalUpDown Controls - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two DecimalUpDown Controls in my Window. One should show the maximum Value the other one minimum Value of the TextBox.
The minimum control can not have greater values than the maximum one and vice versa.

[image]

Notice that the red values are wrong one.

How can I implement this? I am using the MVVM pattern.

Thank you.
Steve

Comment: Is it possible to DataBind the MinimumValueUpDown's MaxValue Property to MaximumValueUpDown's Value? And vice versa? That would be my first Idea.

Comment: You said MVVM. Show xaml and view model. Then it will be easier to give an answer. Though the question is a bit broad, search "validation wpf". I'd simply throw in setter and use [`ExceptionValidationRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions(v=vs.110).aspx), others might decide to go with converters or [coercion](http://drwpf.com/blog/2010/05/05/value-coercion-for-the-masses/) (dependency properties in dedicated user control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the validation logic in your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int _min;
    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    private int _max;
    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public string Error { get { return null; } }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch(columnName)
            {
                case "Min":
                    if (_min > _max)
                        return "Min cannot be greater than Max";
                    break;
                case "Max":
                    if (_max < _min)
                        return "Max cannot be smaller than Min";
                    break;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Min,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Max,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about how data validation in WPF works: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/.

You basiclly implement either the `IDataErrorInfo` or the newer `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in your view model.

Comment: if I created the Window dynamically, that means I have a list of DecimalUpDowns. Is there any chance to use this solution for it?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. And include some sample code that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score -1):

as I understand you need to compare max and min values in setters of your VM properties

Answer (score -2):

You can use onChange event from the text box . (select your textBox and check the event window you will find all events)

Wen change => compare value 
if error => show message

Comment: Hi @AhdBk Thank you for your suggestion, but I really need the two DecimalUpDown to compare each other. The TextBox is just for demonstration purposes