# Check for Valid Values between two DecimalUpDown created dynamically - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

this question is related to this post: [Check for Valid Values between two DecimalUpDown Controls - MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465143/check-for-valid-values-between-two-decimalupdown-controls-mvvm?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The two DoubleUpDown are created dynamically. How can I check for validation between these two, according to maximum and minimum values. (maximum value [first control] can not be lower than the minimum value [second control]).

XAML code:

```
<Window ....>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfControls}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value={Binding Value, ValidationOnDataErrors=True" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </StackPanel>  
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    _listOfControls = new List<CreateControl>()
    {
      new CreateControl { Value = 0.0 },
      new CreateControl { Value = 0.0 }
    };
  }

  private List<CreateControl> _listOfControls;
  public List<CreateControl> ListOfControls
  {
    get { return _listOfControls; }
    set { _listOfControls = value; }
  }
}
```

CreateControl.cs

```
public class CreateControl : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private double _value;
  public double Value
  {
    get { return _value; }
    set { _value = value; }
  }

  public string Error { get { return null; } }
  public string this[string columnName]
  {
    get
    {
      // Error handling code here
      return null;
    }
  }

  PropertyChanged Event ...
}
```

thank you

Comment: What's the point of using an ItemsControl if there are always two DoubleUpDown controls? None.

Answer (score -1):

If you are always creating two controls, one for the maximum value and another one for the minimum value, it makes no sense to use an `ItemsControl` because then the number of controls isn't really dynamic after all.

So remove the `ItemsControl` and use the approach that I suggested in your previous question:

```
<Window ....>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding Min, ValidationOnDataErrors=True" />
        <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding Max, ValidationOnDataErrors=True" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

An `ItemsControl` doesn't seem like the right choice here.

Comment: Is there anyways doing it with ItemsControl? Because this is what I have right now.

Comment: It makes no sense to use an ItemsControl to display two controls. How are you supposed to map the Value property to either a min or a max?

Comment: I know.. But this is just an example. In my real world application I have up to 8 controls created with ItemsControl

Comment: Then your question doesn't make much sense. If you have 8 controls, which is min and which is max...?